# Pass data from app to the same app installed in another device in android

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

I need to pass some data like phone number, email address and etc from my app to the same app but installed in another device. Is it possible to use the phone number to do this? I'm not pertaining to sms messaging, but sending data through the app. If yes, how? I haven't seen any tutorial regarding this matter. If no, what other ways could I accomplish this? I have read about Socket Programming. But I don't quite get on what ip addresses and ports should I use. And I have read that communication device will be the client while the receiving device will be the server. So the data will only a one way trip. I want it to be able to communicate with each other.

Anyone have suggestions regarding this matter? Any suggestions and tutorials will be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: If devices are in close proximity then you can choose NFC or Bluetooth.

Comment: This won't be possible since my app is a tracker.

Answer (score 1):

You can use push notification have a look at http://elsoufy.blogspot.fr/2012/12/push-notifications-with-parsecom.html

Comment: Is this all free? Is it like having a free server? I'll try to look on this link. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you can use phone number as an ID but you can't use it to send data. Your app must have internet access to do what you want. Basically what you need is a server that synchronizes the devices and let them exchange data.

Rough example model:

Client A <----> `http://yourServer.com/messageParser.php` <----> Client B

Your data is sent by using http POST method.

Comment: I'm retrieving the sim card's serial and uses it as an ID. Well, having an internet access is a must, so my main problem is establishin a server for my app. Regarding this server, should I purchase one? I'm new to this kind of approach. Do you have any suggestions on how should I start if I will be using a server?

Comment: I don't have much experience in that area, but I know that you can find a free webspace and set up your server there. You can use java or php to implement the server side to forward your information.